# MySQL - Count all article visitors based on their IP address and access timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table filled with each user's access. One line is one access.
In each row there are field like ID, TIMESTAMP, IP_ADDRESS, ARTICLE_ID,...

Now, the problem is an application used for logging users can't be modified by me, but adds 3 rows instead of one - logging not only the desired article but also one on the left and one on the right (based on ARTICLE_ID).

I want to count all article visits eliminating the ballast around. How can I do that? Overall I need to count in middle row's ARTICLE_ID access but leave the surroundings out.

My original idea is to have some PHP function like this (but I am open to ideas):

```
$logged_article_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT article_id FROM " . $table_name . " GROUP BY article_id", ARRAY_A);

foreach($logged_article_ids as $article) {
// Count in each visit if IP and timestamp is unique or if it is in the middle of 3 lines with equal IP and timestamp.
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

**Update based on comments:**
Is ARTICLE_ID unique in the entries? No, it is not. As suggested here is the sample structure:

```
+---+-----------------+-------------+------------+----
|ID |      TIME       | IP_ADDRESS  | ARTICLE_ID | etc..
+---+-----------------+-------------+------------+----
| 1 | 22-3-2015 11:00 | 134.3.4.104 |     43     |
| 2 | 22-3-2015 11:00 | 134.3.4.104 |     34     |
| 3 | 22-3-2015 11:00 | 134.3.4.104 |     12     |
| 4 | 22-3-2015 11:00 | 32.3.42.203 |     12     |
| 5 | 22-3-2015 11:01 | 32.3.42.203 |     43     |
+---+-----------------+-------------+------------+----
```

In the above table the desired behaviour would be to count middle line article of same IP_ADDRESS and TIME in and also the other standalone lines. So in this case articles 34, 12 and 43 would have each 1 visit while leaving out article 43 and 12 from IP: 134.3.4.104 at 22-3-2015 11:00. However if time or IP was different, I would like this:

```
+---+-----------------+-------------+------------+----
|ID |      TIME       | IP_ADDRESS  | ARTICLE_ID | etc..
+---+-----------------+-------------+------------+----
| 1 | 22-3-2015 11:00 | 134.3.4.104 |     43     |
| 2 | 22-3-2015 11:24 | 134.3.4.104 |     34     |
| 3 | 22-3-2015 11:24 | 32.3.42.203 |     12     |
| 4 | 22-3-2015 11:24 | 32.3.42.203 |     12     |
| 5 | 22-3-2015 19:30 | 32.3.42.203 |     43     |
+---+-----------------+-------------+------------+----
```

Article 43: 2 visitors, 34: 1 visitor, 12: 2 visitors

I thought of adding an additional variable to my above foreach cycle which would remember last cycle's TIMESTAMP and IP_ADDRESS. That is probably a way to go but I haven't been able to test it yet. Also I would prefer a database way but that is too far from my abilities.

Once again thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is ARTICLE_ID unique in the entries?  Meaning the three log entries for a single request have different ARTICLE_IDs?

Comment: Please show sample data from the table.  How do you know which is the correct article you want to count?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Based on your suggestion I've extended my question. @user2182349: You'll notice that ARTICLE_ID can be repetitive - it is just a basic log.

Comment: Since order is not determined in the system in your first exacmple it seems as if you would want to count 34 while tossing article 43 and 12.  However, it's plausible that article 43 was the "Middle" article, just that the DB rendered 43 first in this occurrence.  so what determines the "Middle" one?

Comment: @xQbert: Yes, you're right, in the first example table I want to toss out article 43 and 12. That is also what I mentioned right below that example. So the middle is determined like this: 3 lines with equal TIMESTAMP and IP_ADDRESS ... take the second and toss first and last (third).

Comment: @xQbert: Ups, ok, now I think I understand your comment. Well, if there are 3 lines with equal TIMESTAMP and IP_ADDRESS, their ID's should follow and be something like 4,5,6 ... so I would need to select line with ID 5.

Comment: My point is "Middle" is arbitrary.  the data isn't sorted and the DB can render each in any order unless an order by is defined.  So one time you might get order 43,34,12.. and another time you might get 12,43,34... and another 34,12,43.  the DB engine isn't obligated to return the data in the same order each time thus we can't determine middle consistently.

Comment: @xQbert: As you mention I can order it in ascending order based on ID in which case the correct order should be followed. Also, as there is such ballast in the table I don't count on 100% correct data because some unusual situation may occur ... but there is no heavy traffic so the probability of odd events should be really low.